# Git Checkout Clarification

Tags: git, github

Ok I have a series of file on my directory that I haven't committed yet on github or git remote and I added several files already on my current working files.

Let's say I have a commit that I want checkout previously would that delete my current added files or will just checkout the changes I made on my previous files commit?

My purpose here is to get exactly the same files on my previous version deleting the new files I added since I got an error from it. It's just that its hard to figure out w/c gem should I remove (if I will do it manually) so i prefer to checkout and get the files I have previously and startover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i'm understanding correctly, you are wanting to revert your state to the last known good version?

If this is the case, you can use `git log` to find the commit you want, and then you can either checkout that commit (which would leave you in a headless state) or use `git reset <mode> <commit>`.  use `git reset --hard <commit>` if you are not interested in saving your updates